# Are there alternative proofs of Euler Characteristic being Alternating sum of Homology

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

I am referring to the theorem that $\chi(X)=\sum_{n}(-1)^n\text{rank}\,H_n(X)$.

The proof I know (Hatcher pg 146-147) uses the short exact sequences $0\to Z_n\to C_n\to B_{n-1}\to 0$ and $0\to B_n\to Z_n\to H_n\to 0$.

While that proof is very nice, I am just curious if there exists alternate proofs?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of Euler characteristic ?

Comment: Alternatively, you could show that the Eucler Characteristic is the Alternating sum of Cohomology, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2671964/euler-characteristic-as-alternating-sum-of-cohomology). By dualizing this gives another alternative proof.

Comment: @DietrichBurde : in this question the OP already assumed that $\chi(X) = \sum_n (-1)^n \text{rank} H_n(X)$

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet He only says "I know the analogous proof for homology", but I don't see where it is used in the answer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde : good point.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet My definition would be $\sum_{n}(-1)^nc_n$, where $c_n$ is the number of $n$-cells of $X$.

Comment: For manifolds, I think it can probably be done 'axiomatically'. That is, the Euler characteristic is the unique function mapping $n$-manifolds to integers which satisfies $\chi(\{\ast\}) = 1$, $\chi(M\times N) = \chi(M)\chi(N)$, $\chi(M \sqcup N) = \chi(M) + \chi(N)$ and $\chi(M\# N) = \chi(M)+\chi(N)-(1+(-1)^n)$ (you might also need an axiom equivalent to homotopy invariance?). Then you just need to show that both the homological definition of $\chi$ and the alternating sum of number of cells definition both satisfy those axioms.